# Catch-all field for unserialisable data of serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a route where meta-data can be POSTed. If known fields are POSTed, I would like to store them in a structured manner in my DB, only storing unknown fields or fields that fail validation in a `JSONField`.

Let's assume my model to be:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models


class MetaData(models.Model):
  shipping_address_zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
  ...
  unparseable_info = models.JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I would like to use the built-in serialisation logic to validate whether a `zip_code` is valid (5 letters or less). If it is, I would proceed normally and store it in the `shipping_address_zip_code` field. If it fails validation however, I would like to store it as a key-value-pair in the `unparseable_info` field and still return a success message to the client calling the route.

I have many more fields and am looking for a generic solution, but only including one field here probably helps in illustrating my problem.

Comment: yes you can do that in serializers

Comment: In your view, you can check if the serializer is valid or not. If it is, call `save()`. If it's not, create a new `MetaData` instance and save the invalid data received to `unparseable_info`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are looking for a generic solution, there are a few points that you should consider:

1. Make sure not to place any `model-level` validations in your model as you want it to get saved irrespective of the validation status.
2. Only validate on the `serializer-level` with custom validation methods.
3. Make `unparseable_info` field `read-only` as it is something we don't want the user to send but receive.
4. Make use of the `errors` dictionary provided by the serializer as it gets populated with field-specific errors when we call `is_valid`.

This is how it might translate into code, inside `models.py`:

```
class MetaData(models.Model):
  shipping_address_zip_code = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
  ...
  unparseable_info = models.JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
```

then inside `serializers.py`:

```
class MetaDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MetaData
        read_only_fields = ('unparseable_info', )
        fields = '__all__'
    
    # Write validators for all of your fields.
```

finally inside your `views.py` method, something like this (you can do this inside serializer's `save` method as well):

```
meta_data = MetaDataSerializer(data=request.data)

if not meta_data.is_valid():
    meta_data.unparseable_info = meta_data.errors

meta_data.save()
# Return meta_data.data in JSONResponse.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Django serializer that store fields that fail validation in JSONField.

Here is an example that worked for me:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class MetaDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
model = MetaData
fields = 'all'
def validate_shipping_address_zip_code(self, value):
    if len(value) > 5:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Zip code must be 5 characters or less.")
    return value

def create(self, validated_data):
    unparseable_info = {}
    for field, value in self.initial_data.items():
        try:
            validated_data[field] = self.fields[field].run_validation(value)
        except serializers.ValidationError as e:
            unparseable_info[field] = value
    instance = MetaData.objects.create(**validated_data)
    if unparseable_info:
        instance.unparseable_info = unparseable_info
        instance.save()
    return instance
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 def validate_shipping_address_zip_code(self, value):
      if value >= 5:
        return value
      else:
          raise serializers.ValidationError("Message Here")
```

there's much more validators in serializer look into more detail
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Comment: Thank you, but that does not really solve my problem. If the validation fails, no model is created at all. I would however like a model to be created regardless and only store the contents of the fields which failed the validation in a separate field.